# Neo4J Browser Issue: Graph icon missing

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I am not able to see the graph icon on the Neo4J browser launched from the Desktop application. Does anyone know how to get that button?

[image: 1]

Comment: What's the query you're running?

Comment: Nothing complex , I am trying to represent all values of a row from a CSV file to individual nodes for visualization. The icon itself is missing as in the figure above.

Comment: cybersam's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neo4j browser would only show the `Graph` icon for a query that returns any nodes or paths -- since those are the only things that one can visualize graphically.